# In Neo4J, how to match all nodes that are relted to nodes that all relate to a specific node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose I have Red, Blue and Green nodes (`R`, `B`, `G`) and the relationships might look like this:

[image: Graph showing R -> B <- C]

As you can see, `R` points to `B` and `G` also points to `B`. I want to match all `R` nodes where all the `B` nodes they point to are also related to a specific `G` node. How would I do this?

You can set this up on your own database by running something like this:

```
CREATE 
    (R1:Test_R),
    (B1:Test_B),
    (G:Test_G),
    (R2:Test_R),
    (B2:Test_B),
    (R1)-[:TEST_LINK]->(B1),
    (R1)-[:TEST_LINK]->(B2),
    (R2)-[:TEST_LINK]->(B1),
    (G)-[:TEST_LINK]->(B1)
RETURN
    R1, R2, B1, B2, G
```

You can then query them by running something like this:

```
MATCH
    (R:Test_R)-[:TEST_LINK]->(B:Test_B)
OPTIONAL MATCH
    (B)<-[:TEST_LINK]-(G:Test_G)
RETURN
    R,B,G
```

Comment: I would be interested in cleaner, more elegant queries than the one I have used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a query something like the following:

```
MATCH
    (R:Test_R)-[:TEST_LINK]->(B:Test_B)
WITH
    {R: R, B: COLLECT(B) } AS d
MATCH
    (G:Test_G)
WHERE   
    ID(G) = 5770 // Match our specific G node
    AND ALL(b IN d.B WHERE (b)<-[:TEST_LINK]-(G) )
RETURN d.R
```

The ALL function will return true if all items in the `list` return true for the predicate specified:

```
ALL(<variable> IN <list> WHERE <predicate)
```